# Are any alternatives to the Active Record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Are any alternatives to the Active Record in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but not very easy.

In rails 3 the ORM layer will be pluggable and thus plugging in another ORM layer will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

[Datamapper](http://datamapper.org/doku.php) is the biggest alternative ORM but there are others.

I steer clear because when you use these you really end up on your own out on the bleeding edge and as yet I haven't a need that justified the risk.